# apache(httpd) load balancer and restfull requests

Tags: java, apache, cxf, load-balancing

I use apache httpd as a load balancer and all the soap requests are working properly and are being navigating through the load balancer. but the problem is that all my restfull request to the load balancer returns 404.

I attached the load balancer configuration, and the java webservice code here:

```
 Listen 7060

<VirtualHost *:7060>
        ServerName domain.com
        ProxyRequests off
        <Proxy balancer://mycluster>

                # StartBalancerMember
                BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:7071/
                BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:7072/
                BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:7073/
                BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:7074/
                BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:7075/
                BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:7076/
                BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:7077/
                BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:7078/
                BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:7079/
                # EndBalancerMember

                # Security "technically we aren't blocking anyone but this the place to make those chages
                Order Deny,Allow
                Deny from none
                Allow from all
                # Load Balancer Settings We will be configuring a simple Round Robin style load balancer.  This means that all webheads take an equal share of of the load.
                ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
        </Proxy>
        # balancer-manager This tool is built into the mod_proxy_balancer module and will allow you to do some simple modifications to the balanced group via a gui web interface.
        <Location /balancer-manager>
                SetHandler balancer-manager
                # I recommend locking this one down to your your office
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Location>
        # Point of Balance This setting will allow to explicitly name the the location in the site that we want to be balanced, in this example we will balance "/" or everything in the site.
        ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
        ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/

</VirtualHost>


@Service
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("/executionRest")
public class RestWebService {

    @Resource
    private ExecutionManager executionManager;

    @GET
    @Path("/restTest")
    public String testInvocation() {
        return "Rest test";
    }
}
```

If i enter directly to the first member uri in browser:

```
http://localhost:7071/bdes/ws/rs/executionRest/restTest
```

i get "Rest test" as response

but if i enter in browser:

```
http://localhost:7060/bdes/ws/rs/executionRest/restTest
```

i get 404!

Do i miss something or it's configuration problem in my load balancer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do the apache logs say?

Comment: access_log:[09/Jun/2013:18:46:34 +0300] "GET /bdes/ws/rs/executionRest/restTest HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36"

Comment: Thanx found the problem in the error logs file: proxy_util.c(2102): proxy: connecting http://127.0.0.1:7071//bdes/ws/rs/executionRest/restTest to 127.0.0.1:7071